# greensql alternative for sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a tool for sql server that has similar functions to greensql (SQL inj protection).
[Greensql website](http://greensql.com)

Comment: What is the problem with this product that you want to find something different that does the same thing?

Comment: As far as I understand greensql only works with mysql and postgresql

Comment: It also works with Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most client platforms that talk to sql server have support for query parameters.  So you'll send a command to the server with a placeholder (variable name) for a value that looks like this:

```
SELECT columns FROM [table] WHERE ID= @SomeParameter
```

The client code will send along the value for @SomeParameter boxed up separately from the actually sql code, and it's set up similar to a variable in tsql so it is *never* substituted into the query string directly.  Data is data, code is code, and never the two shall mix.

You could put anything you want in there, and no matter what you try it's never to to be executed as code. It just won't happen. This is *better* than a sanitization audit, because you never have to worry about bugs in the parser, what happens when the next version of Sql Server adds a new feature that breaks the old parser, or if your sanitzer is mangling queries.

So if you build your apps correctly, there's not a real need for such a product in sql server.  Now, it's possible that this kind of product might *enforce* the use of good procedures by your developers (or just act as a background layer in case they do it wrong), but it seems to me that it would be better to spend your energy on getting it right in the first place.

The auditing features, on the other hand, look more interesting to me.  A CTO could put this product between the DB Servers and the DBA's.  The DBA's would still have full access to the server, but the CTO would have a way to audit them where they can't cover their tracks.

And using 'audit' in conjunction with sql server rather than 'injection' as the search vector in google now turns up a few products, including this one:
http://www.enforcive.com/

Comment: This is a GREAT answer. Although I have a question about this parameters and why it is not going to happen. I understand basics of SQL, but still this looks very unfamiliar to me. What if Our @someparameter will have a value, say: "Redmond'; drop table OrdersTable--" It's still sql inj. " it's never to to be executed as code. It just won't happen.". How it is going to execute then?

Comment: The parameter is checked against type. If the ID column is int, the "'Redmond';drop table... " will not be converted and will throw exception. If the ID column is varchar, it will take the string and use it as the value to look for. In this case it will not return any rows if you don't happen to have idendifier with such value.

Comment: @user - this _isn't_ what happens, but you can think of it as if it runs code like this:  `DECLARE @SomeParameter varchar(25); SET @SomeParameter = GetPassedParameterValue(0); SELECT ... WHERE SomeColumn = @SomeParameter`